# Get current website id in admin

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, admin, scope, websites

I am in the admin and my structure of the scopes is the following:

```
-> Default
----> Website A
--------> Store DE
--------> Store FR
----> Website B
--------> Store DE
--------> Store FR
```

So, now I am simply reloading the page and in the `_afterLoad()` method, in my custom Model, which extends the core backend model where, which redirects to my _afterLoad method, I want to get the ID of the current website, that I am loading (when I change the Scope from the upper left drop-down menu).

`Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()` does not help, because it always returns 0. I can get the store code, when I am loading one of the store scopes, and from this get their IDs, but the websites don't have codes, so this cannot help me either.
`Mage::getModel('core/website')->getWebsite->getId()` does not work either.

I know that the IDs of `website A` and `website B` are respectively 1 and 2, but I don't know how to acquire them, when I am in the admin.

Comment: How does the url look like when you select a website from the dropdown?

Comment: @Marius - `mydomain/admin/system_config/edit/section/xmlimport/website/base/key/b12439235f4523df996e9fd79a1b6cb398883ec8dd3d1b0501b730858a52d79f/`

Comment: @Marius - I now saw that when I get to `website B` the url is `.../website/nameOfWebsiteB/...`. Do you suggest I get the code of the website from the URL with a GET ?

Comment: yep...that's what I'm suggesting. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$websiteCode = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('website');
if ($websiteCode) {
    $website = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($websiteCode);
    $websiteId = $website->getId();
    //do your magic with $websiteId
}
else {
    //it means you didn't select a website - either you selected a store view or default.
}
```