# get current store id for backend system configuration

Tags: magento-1.6

For my shipping module, I have created a block which has group of form element.

```
<options translate="label">
    <label>Other Settings</label>                            
    <frontend_model>Namespace_Module_Block_Form_Field_Options</frontend_model>
    <sort_order>172</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
</options>
```

And this is block which I have created.

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Form_Field_Options extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field {
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element) {
        $value = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/namespace_module/optionalfield');
        $xhtml = '<input type="text" class="input-text" value="'.$value.'" name="groups[namespace_module][fields][optionalfield][value]" />';
        return $xhtml;
    }
}
```

In this block I have create more many options, It is working fine. But the issue is that in `system->configuration`, 
  `Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/namespace_module/optionalfield');` is returning value which is saved in default config, And not showing value according to the store selected.

In each store `Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/namespace_module/optionalfield');` is showing value which is saved in default config.

So I think I use this code `Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/namespace_module/optionalfield',$store_id)` than it will show me values according to store selected in `system->configuration`.

So guide me how to get store id in this block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
if (strlen($code = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getStore())) // store level
{
    $store_id = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($code)->getId();
}
elseif (strlen($code = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getWebsite())) // website level
{
    $website_id = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($code)->getId();
    $store_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website_id)->getDefaultStore()->getId();
}
else // default level
{
    $store_id = 0;
}
```

you can take more idea from

[How to get current store id from current scope in admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6833/how-to-get-current-store-id-from-current-scope-in-admin)

[Get current website id in admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22190/get-current-website-id-in-admin)

Answer (score 0):

I used this one

```
if (strlen($code = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store'))) { // store level
            $store_id = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($code)->getId();
        } elseif (strlen($code = $code = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('website'))) { // website level
            $website_id = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($code)->getId();
            $store_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website_id)->getDefaultStore()->getId();
        } else { // default level
            $store_id = 0;
        }
```

and that worked fine for me